# Tab icon guidelines

Tags: android, icons, tabactivity

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#tabstructure

Are we sure this page was written correctly?  It states that **UNSELECTED** icons must be "**WHITE**"; and **SELECTED** icons must be "**GRAY**".  This seems backwards and looks quite odd in my application.

Comment: no one forces you to follow these lines. This is merely if you want to match android design. But as several android phones have their own UI like the HTC sense.... well as long as you don't do something ugly and homongenous in your app, I think everything's fine. They are guide lines, not laws

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I like the way the icons turn out, but I don't like that white is unselected and gray is selected.  I think I'm going to flip them.  I think it looks much cleaner.  The default Android apps seem to agree.  For example, the contacts app uses white as selected and gray as unselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct for Eclair (2.0/2.1) and FroYo (2.2) Android UIs.  I'm not so sure about the UIs from 1.x, though.

Sense/Motoblur might have their own standards.

Answer (score 0):

That's very true since usually active tab background is white and inactive tabs are gray.

Comment: Using the default style for TabView (API 2.1), active tabs are gray and inactive tabs are a very dark charcoal.  Placing a gray icon on a gray tab is not particularly pleasing to me.  Additionally, a white icon on a very dark charcoal is too contrasting